Dates changing format when running excel macro
I have this excel macro to clean excel files and remove hard spacing and non printable characters, but nothing to do with changing the dates format or anything at all but when its saved as a unicode text file i get surprised the dates changed format
Macro;
Sub CleanAndSaveEachSheetAsUnicodeText()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim originalPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim chunkSize As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim cellValue As String
    
    ' Set the chunk size for processing data
    chunkSize = 1000 ' Adjust as needed based on your data size
    
    ' Disable screen updating and automatic calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Find the last column with data in the worksheet
        lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        ' Get the last row with data
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Process data in chunks
        For i = 1 To lastRow Step chunkSize
            ' Determine the end row for the current chunk
            Dim endRow As Long
            endRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(i + chunkSize - 1, lastRow)
            
            ' Load data chunk into an array
            data = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(endRow, lastCol)).Value
            
            ' Process each cell in the chunk
            For j = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
                For k = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
                    ' Check if the cell contains a value
                    If Not IsEmpty(data(j, k)) Then
                        ' Convert Chr(160) to space
                        cellValue = Replace(data(j, k), Chr(160), " ")
                        
                        ' Apply CLEAN function
                        cellValue = Application.Clean(cellValue)
                        
                        ' Remove line breaks and trim excess spaces
                        cellValue = Replace(cellValue, vbLf, " ")
                        cellValue = Replace(cellValue, vbCrLf, " ")
                        cellValue = Replace(cellValue, vbCr, " ")
                        cellValue = Trim(cellValue)
                        
                        ' Update cell value
                        data(j, k) = cellValue
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
            
            ' Write cleaned data chunk back to the worksheet
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(endRow, lastCol)).Value = data
        Next i
        
        ' Columns AutoFit
        ws.Columns.AutoFit
        
        ' Get the original file path
        originalPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        
        ' Extract the sheet name
        fileName = ws.Name
        
        ' Save the worksheet as Unicode text with the sheet name in the same folder as the original file
        Dim filePath As String
        filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName & ".txt"
        ws.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
    Next ws
    
    ' Enable screen updating and automatic calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

A clean converted text file where the data is untouched

Please explain your surprise :-) What is unexpected?

xD the dates, for example in the original excel file theyll be in mm/dd/yyyy but when the macro is ran and the file saved in unicode txt file the dates will be in dd/mm/yyyy

Dates in Excel are binary values, they have no format. The actual representation is a float representing an OLE Automation Date. The way they're displayed is controlled by the cell's numeric style and the end user's locale. Dates in the US and every other country will appear differently because no country except the US puts months at the front

saved in .. txt file Excel files aren't text files. When you export the Excel contents to a text file the binary values like numbers and dates will get converted using either the user's locale or the locale you explicitly specify. The only universally recognizable date format is ISO8601 anyway. If you want' to create a CSV file that can be parsed everywhere you'll have to export to

Okay so what i do is i get the excel files run this macro to clean the columns then they get saved into txt files then I import them into a software called ACL where i continue working on them, so if i understand correctly the dates are changed due to the systems locales? and the macro has nothing wrong ?

Pretty much, yes.  If you want complete control over the format of the output then you could write the txt file directly from the data array.
